# LINQ to Entities LastOrDefault is NULL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, linq

I am trying to return the Last Value of "rfIDH" where the last value is "null". Below is my code.

```
Public Function checkrfidh(ByVal ptrhID As Integer) As String

    Return (From _tr As TransTransactionReference In TranCTX.TransTransactionReferences Where _tr.trhID = ptrhID Select _tr.rfIDH).LastOrDefault

End Function
```

[image: Sample Data]

Please Help Beginner here...

Comment: I guess you misunderstood what `LastOrDefault` does. According to MSDN it `Returns the last element of a sequence, **OR** a default value if the sequence contains no elements.`. You need to check for `...Where rfIDH is Null`. Also what do you mean with Last? You don´t have included any order by so the last item returned might not be what you expect.

Comment: Please give an example what you expect as last item in regards of your screen.

Comment: Your comment does not make sense. If rfIdh is null it cannot be "A". Please give a minimal, complete and veriviable example. Add it to your question and not as comment.